# Sum of integers using XOR, AND gates

Tags: boolean, operator-keyword

How to compute sum of two integers using bit wise NOT, XOR, AND,and OR operators, without using SHIFT operator (not using arithmetic operators as well)? Is it possible ?

Example C code:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 11;
int c = a ^ b;
int d = a & b;
int sum = ...
```

Comment: You're talking XOR, AND gates in combination with SHIFT operators which makes me confused. Yes, you can build it with gates, however the result of two bits and a carry added needs to be connected to the input of the same operation on the next higher bit which would then possibly be counted as some kind of SHIFT. Can't be much clearer without you explaining the actual problem in a bit more detail though.

Comment: Does that mean that you cannot use neither NOT nor OR?

Comment: NOT and OR both OK, can be used

Comment: Edited the question by your comments, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take `a = b = 1`. The result of this sum is `sum = 2`. The binary representation of the inputs are `00000001` (let's have 8-bits for simplicity). The output is `00000010`. You can easily get the least significant bit, `LSB = a0 XOR b0`, but to modify the bit number 1 you need a shift.